# Most common and second most common values in 3D numpy array along last axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I would like to know the top 2 most common values and their frequencies along the last axis of my numpy array. I already have this working, but I'd like to get it to run faster.

### Example case

The real data is a (720, 1280, 64) shaped numpy array of type uint16, but for simplicity, let's imagine it's a (2, 2, 4) array instead.

So the data would be like this:

```
               0          1  
          ------------------------
        0 | [1,1,1,2] [1,1,2,2]
        1 | [2,2,2,1] [1,1,1,3]
```

For each x, y position, I would like to know what is the most common and second most common value, and how many times the most common and second most common value appear (if two values are equally common, picking either one is fine).

So for the above example, the most common values would be:

```
               0          1  
          ------------------------
        0 |    1          1
        1 |    2          1
```

And how many times they appear:

```
               0          1  
          ------------------------
        0 |    3          2
        1 |    3          3
```

The second most common values (in case there is no second most common value, putting zero there is fine) in the example are:

```
               0          1  
          ------------------------
        0 |    2          2
        1 |    1          3
```

And how often the second most common value appears. If there is no second most common value, putting anything here would be fine.

```
               0          1  
          ------------------------
        0 |    1          2
        1 |    1          1
```

### Current solution

If the array is called "a", I first do this to get the most common value and its number of appearances:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode

a = np.array([
    [[1,1,1,2], [1,1,2,2]],
    [[2,2,2,1], [1,1,1,3]]
])

most_common_value, most_common_count = mode(a, axis=2)
print(most_common_value.squeeze())
print(most_common_count.squeeze())
```

**Output:**

```
[[1 1]
 [2 1]]

[[3 2]
 [3 3]]
```

Then to get the second most common value, I just remove the most common value and then run the above again. To remove, I first create a mask of which values I want to remove.

```
mask = a == most_common_value
print(mask)
```

**Output:**

```
array([[[ True,  True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True, False, False]],

       [[ True,  True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True,  True, False]]])
```

Now what I'd really like to true is remove everything that is True, but since the dimension has to remain the same along the axis, instead of actually removing anything, I replace the most common value with NaNs instead.

Since these are uint16s that don't know about NaNs, I have to convert to float first.

```
a = a.astype('float')
np.putmask(a, mask, np.nan)
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[[[nan nan nan  2.]
  [nan nan  2.  2.]]

 [[nan nan nan  1.]
  [nan nan nan  3.]]]
```

Now `mode` can be run again on this, except it needs to be told to ignore the NaNs, and the result needs to be converted to uint16 again.

```
m = mode(a, axis=2, nan_policy='omit')
m = [x.astype('uint16') for x in m]
second_most_common_value, second_most_common_count = m
print(second_most_common_value.squeeze())
print(second_most_common_count.squeeze())
```

**Output:**

```
[[2 2]
 [1 3]]

[[1 2]
 [1 1]]
```

At this point I have all the most and second most common values and how many times they appear on the axis, so I'm done.

### Performance

As I mentioned, this solution works, but is slow. Here is the above repeated, but as a script with realistic data that you can try running. I also [put it up on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/7kePvBYF) in case that's easier to copy from.

**Self-contained example:**

```
import time
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode

a = np.random.randint(30000, size=(720, 1280, 64))

start_time = time.time()

most_common_value, most_common_count = mode(a, axis=2)

mask = a == most_common_value
a = a.astype('float')
np.putmask(a, mask, np.nan)

m = mode(a, axis=2, nan_policy='omit')
m = [x.astype('uint16') for x in m]
second_most_common_value, second_most_common_count = m

end_time = time.time()
print(f'Took {end_time-start_time:.2f} seconds to run')
```

**Output:**

```
Took 123.29 seconds to run
```

Ideally this should run in less than 30 seconds, but any improvement is welcome.

### Why do you want to do this?

As you may have noticed, the first two dimensions of (720, 1280, 64) are the 1280x720 image resolution. The 64 values for each pixel are the colors of subpixels under that pixel, and refer to a known palette of colors by index.

To know how to color each pixel, I need to know the two most common palette colors so I can mix them. The data comes from Blender from a scene I created, so I know that there is almost always only two different palette colors for each pixel.

The point of this project is to improve rendering quality on [my website](https://hattemi.com/) where users can create instant custom animations;  solving this would get rid of jagged edges in the renderings.

Since my animation has 600 frames, it would take about a day to run this for each frame, and I'd prefer to be able to start running it when going to sleep and have the finished results available in the morning, so for this reason I want to improve performance just a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a simple mode that iterates over all values of the final axis, trying each to see if it might be the new mode. This naive solution still ended up being twice as fast as `scipy.stats.mode` for my data.

```
def silly_mode(a):
    """Returns mode and counts for final axis of a numpy array.

    Same as scipy.stats.mode(a, axis=-1).squeeze()
    """

    # Best mode candidate discovered so far
    most_common_value = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1]),dtype=a.dtype)
    most_common_count = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1]),dtype=a.dtype)

    # Silly solution based on just iterating all of final dimension,
    # but still beats scipy if final dimension is less than 100 in length.
    for i in range(0, a.shape[2]):

        # Find candidate value for each cell
        val = np.expand_dims(a[:,:,i], axis = -1)

        # Count how many times it appears
        counts = np.count_nonzero(a == val, axis = -1).astype(a.dtype)

        # Find out which ones should become the new mode values
        update_mask = counts > most_common_count[:,:]

        # Update mode value and its count where necessary
        np.putmask(most_common_value, update_mask, val)
        np.putmask(most_common_count, update_mask, counts)

    return most_common_value, most_common_count
```

This had the added benefit of being possible to extend to finding the second most common values as well, which I think will turn out to be much faster than my hack of taking the mode with scipy, removing the mode values and then finding mode again.

I will update this answer with the way of finding the second most common values once I get that working.

**Update:**

Here is the function for finding the top 2 most common values and their counts. I wouldn't rely on this for anything critical, as it has not been properly tested except by eye for a few test cases.

```
def top_2_most_common_values(a, ignore_zeros = False):
    """Returns mode and counts for each mode of final axis of a numpy array,
    and also returns the second most common value and its counts.

    Similar to calling scipy.stats.mode(a, axis=-1).squeeze() to find the mode,
    except this also returns the second most common values.

    If ignore_zeros is true, then zero will not be considered as a mode candidate.
    In this case a zero instead signifies that there was no most common or second
    most common value, and so the count will also be zero.
    """

    # Silly solution based on just iterating all of final dimension
    most_common_value = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1]),dtype=a.dtype)
    most_common_count = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1]),dtype=a.dtype)
    second_most_common_value = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1]),dtype=a.dtype)
    second_most_common_count = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1]),dtype=a.dtype)

    for i in range(0, a.shape[2]):

        # Find candidate value for each cell
        val = np.expand_dims(a[:,:,i], axis = -1)

        # Count how many times it appears
        counts = np.count_nonzero(a == val, axis = -1).astype(a.dtype)

        # Find out which ones should become the new mode values
        update_mask = counts > most_common_count[:,:]
        if ignore_zeros:
            update_mask &= val.squeeze() != 0

        # If most common value changes, then what used to be most common is now second most common
        # Without the next two lines a like [1,2,2] would fail, as the second most common value
        # is never encountered again after being initially set to be the most common one.
        np.putmask(second_most_common_value, update_mask, most_common_value)
        np.putmask(second_most_common_count, update_mask, most_common_count)        

        # Update mode value and its count where necessary
        np.putmask(most_common_value, update_mask, val)
        np.putmask(most_common_count, update_mask, counts)

        # In a case like [2, 0, 0, 1] the last 1 isn't the new most common value, but it 
        # still should be updated as the second most common value. For these cases separately check 
        # if any encountered value might be the second most common one.
        update_mask = (counts >= second_most_common_count[:,:]) & (val.squeeze() != most_common_value[:,:])
        if ignore_zeros:
            update_mask &= val.squeeze() != 0

        # # Save previous best mode and its count before updating
        np.putmask(second_most_common_value, update_mask, val)
        np.putmask(second_most_common_count, update_mask, counts)

    return most_common_value, most_common_count, second_most_common_value, second_most_common_count
```